# Get wrong noun chunks using spacy doc.noun_chunks

Tags: python, nlp, dependencies, spacy

I use spacy `en_core_web_trf` and `doc.noun_chunks` to get noun chunks. Previously, it worked well, I can get the noun chunks correctly. But recently, since around mid-Dec. 2021 (I guess), I use the same way, same script, but I cannot get the noun chunks correctly. For example, in the following script:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
test_sen = "a label on a box that ensures that the status of a parcel can be traced uniquely "
doc = nlp(test_sen)
# ---------------------get initial noun chunks---------------------
for chunks in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunks)
# displacy.serve(doc, style='dep')
```

I get the following result:

```
a label
a box
that
the status
a parcel
```

But, according to the dependency graph (see below), the text `that`(the first one) should not be a noun chunk, but it is printed as a noun chunk. Also, according to the description of noun chunks from [here](https://spacy.io/api/doc#noun_chunks), it says that the `Doc.noun_chunks: Yields base noun-phrase Span objects`. In whichever cases, the `that` shall not be a so-called `noun chunk`, but it is identified as a noun chunk here, and it causes a lot of trouble for my later processing.

Does anyone have a hint on how to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: With `[chunks for chunks in doc.noun_chunks]`, I get `[a label, a box, the status, a parcel]` as output, no `that`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I have just tried in your way, "chunk = [chunks for chunks in doc.noun_chunks] print(chunk)", but the 'that' is still printed out, I have no idea about the reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are probably due to using a different version of `en_core_web_trf`. There's a new model release for each minor spaCy release, so there are model versions: v3.0.0, v3.1.0, v3.2.0. You can see the currently installed model versions with `spacy validate`.

If you need the exact same annotation for a particular task, specify the exact model version in your requirements:

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_trf-3.1.0/en_core_web_trf-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I think that you're seeing differences due to updates in the v3.2.0 model that improve the POS tags, which are mapped with rules from the fine-grained tags and dependency parse. Some noun chunk errors come from tagger/parser errors, but this looks like the right tag, parse, and POS here. Exact definitions of noun chunk can vary, but in the examples I can find (mainly from the CoNLL 2003 shared task), relative pronouns like this are included as noun chunks.

Comment: Thanks @aab, and thanks for the link to go to version 3.1.0. I have another very very basic question, how can I specify this exact version while I install the en_core_web_trf?  I only found the install command "python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf", and this command only can install the 3.2.0 version. I tried to add "==3.1.0" at the end, it does not work. Can I download the package first from the link, then install it manually and locally? Thanks again!

Comment: "python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf-3.1.0"  also does not work

Comment: `spacy download` only downloads the newest compatible release. `pip install URL` is how to install from that specification. You can also download it and then install the `.whl` file with `pip` directly. If necessary, `pip` will upgrade/downgrade `spacy` in your venv to match the model. v3 models are largely forward-compatible, but if you really want the exact same results every time, then you should also use the same spacy version every time.

Comment: Thank you @aab, your explanation is very clear. It works now, yes, I must use that old version, because if I use the latest version, it influences a *lot on the result.